# Numpy slicing and indexing

Tags: numpy, slice

I have 4 numpy arrays: time_start, time_stop, time1, pressure.
For each element in time_start, I want to find the index of the closest value in time1 and then read the pressure values **from** that index!

Similarly, for each element in time_stop, I want to find the index of the closest value in time1 and then read the pressure values **until** that index!
(time_start and time_stop have the same length)

Here is what i have written:
 a function to find the nearest value:

```
import numpy as np
def find_nearest(array,value):
    idx = (np.abs(array-value)).argmin()
    return array[idx]
```

and then:

```
p = np.zeros(len(time_start), dtype = object)
itemindex_str = np.zeros(len(time_start), dtype = object)
itemindex_stp = np.zeros(len(time_start), dtype = object)

for i in range(0,len(time_start)):

    itemindex_str =np.where(time1==find_nearest(time1,int(time_start[i])))

    itemindex_stp = np.where(time1==find_nearest(time1,int(time_stop[i])))

    p[i] = pressure[itemindex_str:itemindex_stp]
```

and I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "re-written_mobility.py", line 174, in <module>
    p[i] = pressure[itemindex_str:itemindex_stp]
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

It would be very nice if you could help me solve this.
Thank you very much :)

Comment: To start with: why do you not just return the idx? The `np.where` probably returns arrays instead of integers, which makes it slightly difficult to slice. The entire problem is circumvented by returning `idx` -> `itemindex_str = find_nearest(time1, int(time_start[i])))` etc.

Comment: You are right. it is solved now. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Glad to be of help, I added the quickfix as an answer. :)

Comment: `np.where` returns a tuple of arrays, one array for each dimension of the input.  Experiment with it in a simpler interactive session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `np.where` probably returns arrays instead of integers, which makes it slightly difficult to slice. The entire problem is circumvented by returning `idx`.

```
def find_nearest(array,value):
    idx = (np.abs(array-value)).argmin()
    return idx
itemindex_str = find_nearest(time1,int(time_start[i]))
itemindex_stp = find_nearest(time1,int(time_stop[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well your problem, you want this?:

```
result = [pressure[i] for i in [np.abs(time1 - ts).argmin() for ts in time_start]]
```